Delay in Middle Click Gesture After Upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 24.04, and I've noticed a delay (around 0.5 seconds) when using the middle-click gesture (three fingers) on my touchpad. This lag occurs when I try to open applications from the sidebar or close tabs in my browser. I didn’t experience this issue at all in 20.04.
Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any suggestions for how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
